# Keep the style when drag a row

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with a style and when I drag a row the style change.

I check the inspect element but I can't find the solution.

Table looks like this when I don't click:

[image]

And when I click looks like this:

[image]

The view looks like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="table1">
              <table class="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByIdAsc"></span></a>-->ID<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'id','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByIdDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'slug','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderBySlugAsc"></span></a>-->Visible<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order',['field' => 'slug','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderBySlugDown"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByOrderAsc"></span></a>-->Nombre<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'order','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByOrderDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th>Header</th>
                    <th>Home</th>
                    <th class="thcenter"><!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'asc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" id="orderByPublicAsc"></span></a>-->Orden<!--<a href="{{route('admin.projects.order', ['field' => 'public','order' => 'desc'])}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" id="orderByPublicDesc"></span></a>--></th>
                    <th><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>Acciones</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody id="tbodyproject"> 
                  @foreach ($projects as $key => $project)
                    <tr id="{{$project->id}}" class="trdrag">
                      <td class="idrow tdcenter"><p id="margindata">{{$project->id}}</p></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"> @if ($project->public == '1')
                          <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>

                      @else
                      <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindata"></i>
                      @endif
                      </td>
                      <td><p id="margindata">{{$project->slug}}</p></td>
                      <td><img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/header.jpg') }}" class="sizeheader"></td>
                      <td><img src="{{ asset('/storage/projects/'.$project->slug.'/home.jpg')}}" class="sizehome"></td>
                      <td class="tdcenter"><p id="margindata">{{$project->order}}</p></td>
                      <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}" onsubmit="return ConfirmarBorrar()">
                      <td><!--<a href="{{ route('admin.projects.show', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="margindata">View</a>-->
                          <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                                          <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="margindata">
                                          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                      </td>
                      </form>
                    </tr>
                  @endforeach
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery looks like this:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();

$("#tabs ul li a").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        var tabdiv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(tabdiv + " table tr:last").after("<tr>" + ui.draggable.html() + "</tr>");
        ui.draggable.remove();
    }
});

$("#tbodyproject").sortable({
    items: "> tr",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    update: function( event, ui ) {
        let newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:'/admin/projects/updateOrder',
            data: {ids: newOrder}
        })
       .done(function( msg ) {
        location.reload();        
       });
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

How could I keep the style when I make drag 'n' drop? To distinguish it a little, I would like to add a background perhaps a little darker.

Comment: Can you please provide `jsfiddle`, will help you out.

Comment: I think will be hard, cause I have variables who comes from controller. I will try to make something similar. I think maybe in Jquery I can set the css. What do you think? @Shiladitya

Comment: Here you go with the `jsfiddle` link https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/ . Please explain me what is the issue?

Comment: Thanks a lot. When you make the 'drag' style change. I want to keep the same style, maybe with an other background-color.